# OutOfMemoryError while trying to reduce size of byte data using bitmaps

Tags: java, android, performance, bitmap

In my app when i upload an image i want to reduce the data so i call this function. But this piece of code is giving me an outOfMemoryError.

LOGCAT:  09-17 15:32:01.712: E/AndroidRuntime(7771):    at com.technow.pereo.FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(FileHelper.java:64)

```
    public static byte[] reduceImageForUpload(byte[] imageData) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ImageResizer.resizeImageMaintainAspectRatio(imageData,
            SHORT_SIDE_TARGET);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream);
    bitmap.recycle();
    byte[] reducedData = outputStream.toByteArray();
    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Intentionally blank
    }

    return reducedData;
}
```

What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?!

Comment: You could add some information about where *exactly* (i.e. at which line) the error occurs. In general, of course, "out of memory" means that there is no free memory left to store additional data in...

Comment: What is `ImageResizer`? Your own class? That's going to be the problem, we'd have to see that.

Comment: Yes it is my own class

Answer (score 0):

Seems ImageResizer is a custom class. Use the snippet below to re-size the image before you brought the image for further processing.

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```